# Rich list click event

Tags: blackberry

I used the following code to display a rich list.

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.table.*;

public class RichListDemo extends UiApplication
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    RichListDemo theApp = new RichListDemo();       
    theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}

public RichListDemo()
{        
    pushScreen(new RichListScreen());
}


private static class RichListScreen extends MainScreen
{
    public RichListScreen()
    {
        super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);

        setTitle("Rich List Demo");

        add(new LabelField("BlackBerry Devices", LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER));
        add(new SeparatorField());

        Manager mainManager = getMainManager();

        RichList list = new RichList(mainManager, true, 2, 1);

        Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("9500.png");
        Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("9000.png");

        list.add(new Object[] {bitmap1, "Device 1", "BlackBerry Smartphone 9500", "Description of Device 1."});
        list.add(new Object[] {bitmap2, "Device 2", "BlackBerry Smartphome 9000", "Description of Device 2."});
    }
}
}
```

How to implement click event in the Rich List ?. When i click the List, i want to show a dilog box. Is it possible ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot determine the selected row in a `RichList`.  You can use a `TableView` instead  of `RichList` if you want to have click functionality . `RichList` should be used for **read only** items you want to display.  If you want to capture input and/or allow a user to make a selection then a `TableView` should be used.

You can use [this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Using-TableModel-TableView-TableController-and-DataTemplate-to/ta-p/617305) link to create a table view and add clickable fields in the row

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. See the following code:

```
        final RichList list = new RichList(vfm, false,3, 1);

        list.add(new Object[] {"jak się masz", "كيف حالك؟", "Description of Device 1." ,new SeparatorField()});
        list.add(new Object[] { "Device 2", "BlackBerry Smartphome 9000", "Description of Device 2.",new SeparatorField()});
        list.add(new Object[] { "Device 3", "BlackBerry Smartphome 9000", "Description of Device 3.",new SeparatorField()});
        list.add(new Object[] { "Device 4", "BlackBerry Smartphome 9000", "Description of Device 4.",new SeparatorField()});
        list.add(new Object[] { "Device 5", "BlackBerry Smartphome 9000", "Description of Device 5.",new SeparatorField()});
        list.add(new Object[] { "Device 6", "BlackBerry Smartphome 9000", "Description of Device 6.",new SeparatorField()});

        list.setFocusPolicy(TableController.ROW_FOCUS);

     list.setCommand(new Command(new CommandHandler() 
     {
        /**
         * @see net.rim.device.api.command.CommandHandler#execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata, Object)
         */
         public void execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata metadata, Object context) 
         {
        Dialog.alert("executed!");  
        TableModel tableModel = list.getModel();
               Object[] objArray = (Object[])tableModel.getRow(list.getFocusRow());                                
               int DISPLAY_NAME = 0;
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK, (String)objArray[DISPLAY_NAME], 0, null, 0 );          

              dialog.doModal();                                

         }
     }));
```